# Getting 404 error when executing spring MVC

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc

I am getting 404 error every time executing Spring application. I have created the dynamic web project using eclipse. I am new to spring and use eclipse first time. Please help to solve this issue.

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringBasic</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.bt.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />



      <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>


</beans>
```

MyController

```
  package com.bt.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;  

@Controller
public class MyController {


     @RequestMapping("/")
     @ResponseBody
      public ModelAndView loadhellopage() {
         System.out.println("controller");
        String msg="Finally";
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("hellopage");
        mav.addObject("msg", "Finally");
         return mav;
      }

}
```

hellopage.jsp:

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    ${message} 
</body>
</html>
```

this is my folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

Also included all the jar files in lib folder under WEB-INF.

When running the project on apache tomcat it is giving 404 error

Comment: It's giving 404 for *which URL*? Do you realize that only URLs ending with `.do` will go to the Spring servlet, given your web.xml? Why do you still use xml to configure spring, although it advertises Java config for years? I'd strongly advise to use Spring Boot.

Comment: when running the project using eclipse IDE it is giving 404 error for http://localhost:8080/SpringBasic/.
I tried <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> instead of <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern> but same error.

Comment: ResponseBody makes no sense on that controller method, since you precisely want spring to forward to a view. For more help, post the logs, and the complete error message you get.

Comment: Ì tries removing ResponseBody annotation as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..@JBNizet
Please advise how can i post logs here. I am using StackOverflow for the first time.
And also please tell how can i get logs.. Is it the console output?

Comment: try changing the mapping to  `@RequestMapping("home.do")`

Comment: Also, you're adding an object as `"msg"`, so `${message}` needs to be changed.

Comment: No change..:( same error..